# How to build a UI with typescript/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm absolute new to this topic. I want to learn Typescript using NodeJS and have some simple questions. NodeJS is working with Javascript, as far as I know, but how do you get an UI? Do you have to create a HTML/CSS Webpage and run it with Typescript? How do you get Images, Options, Buttons in Typescript? How are they implemented in the Code? I found a lot of Tutorials, but they just return "Hello World" and I don't think I have to "write" the whole page in an output in Typescript.

Comment: I think you are looking for **server-side rendering** (SSR). [Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a popular NodeJS framework for that kind of thing. For a dynamic UI you will need more than SSR however, because you can only serve static pages with it. Have a look at some of the client-side frameworks like [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/).

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is pure server side javascript, you wont build the UI with it, you would serve the html/css/js to the client, and maybe create an API to communicate with the client.

I assume you dont need an example how to create a Node project, as you stated to have read some tutorials about it.

For starters, i would advise to go for **NodeJS** plus **Expressjs** on the server, then maybe start to serve simple static websites (like a handwritten 'index.html'). Expressjs makes development especially in the beginning a lot easier. Serving static files would just need something like

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

..in your server code. If you navigate then to e.g. **localhost:3000/test/route**, it would look for the /test/route/index.html in your public folder (which should be in your project root)

Then use a framework for client side development.

If you want  to use Typescript for the development of the client side of the app, you might want to look into **Angular**. It is pretty tightly bound to Typescript, but the learning curve is pretty harsh if you are a beginner with this. Other client side frameworks that work well with Typecsript pretty much out-of-the-box or via cli are **Vue.js** and **React**, just as examples.